# Deploy different branch other than `master` via `pm2` give `git` error?

Tags: git, pm2

I am using pm2 (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/) to do deployment in my application. But I found I can't deploy on branches other than `master`. Below is my configuration:

```
{
            key: '~/.ssh/aws.pem',
            user: 'ubuntu',
            host: [host],
            ref: 'origin/develop_zy',
            repo: 'git@github.com:zhaoyi0113/xxxxx.git',
            path: '/home/ubuntu/zy',
}
```

I get this error if I set `origin/develop_zy` on ref:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/develop_zy': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

  git reset failed

Deploy failed
1
```

but it works fine if I change it to `origin/master`. I am sure the branch `develop_zy` exist on my repo both locally and remotely. The error looks like a `git` error and when does git give us this error.

How can I deploy in different branches?

Comment: is this your repo https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/MongoDB-Training.git .... i didn't find `develop_zy` branch...

Comment: oh it is just an example. the repos I am really working on is a private repo.

Comment: Did you figure it out how to fix this error? I am facing same issue